# Using conda environment from within Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, conda

There are several packages I need to run an Rstudio rmd to create a markup.  These are kept in a conda environment. Opening Rstudio inside of a conda environment gives me an error, but opening Rstudio outside of it does not.  I know there is a way to specify conda environment with some packages directly, like with reticulate, but **is there a way I can open Rstudio and point to a conda environment so my specific version of R and all my dependencies can be used?**

In case you're wondering about the error starting rstudio within the environment, I've tried uninstalling and re-installing rstudio, deleting the the ~/.local/share/rstudio and ~/.config/rstudio folders. But, no luck.  Here is the error message:

```
unable to initialize the JIT
```

*/home/tjm/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-tjm.log*:

```
2023-04-05T06:11:57.805471Z [rsession-tjm] ERROR R SUICIDE: unable to initialize the JIT; LOGGED FROM: void {anonymous}::rSuicide(const string&) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1241
2023-04-05T06:25:08.469411Z [rsession-tjm] ERROR R SUICIDE: unable to initialize the JIT; LOGGED FROM: void {anonymous}::rSuicide(const string&) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1241
2023-04-05T06:25:08.469411Z [rsession-tjm] ERROR R SUICIDE: unable to initialize the JIT; LOGGED FROM: void {anonymous}::rSuicide(const string&) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1241
```

Edit: Here is some information on the conda environments where launching Rstudio failed, and where importing from reticulate failed.
Environment 1:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.40                 hf600244_0    conda-forge
bwidget                   1.9.14               ha770c72_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.19.0               h5eee18b_0  
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           h06a4308_0    anaconda
cairo                     1.16.0            ha61ee94_1014    conda-forge
curl                      7.88.1               h5eee18b_0  
expat                     2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               h14ed4e7_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               hca18f0e_1    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         12.2.0              hcc96c02_19    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.1               h27087fc_0    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    12.2.0              h55be85b_19    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.14               h295c915_1  
gsl                       2.7.1                h6e86dc7_1  
gxx_impl_linux-64         12.2.0              hcc96c02_19    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  6.0.0                h8e241bc_0    conda-forge
icu                       70.1                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   h0b41bf4_3    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_15    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.4               h568e23c_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.88.1               h91b91d3_0  
libdeflate                1.14                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20221030         h5eee18b_0  
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     12.2.0              h3b97bd3_19    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            12.2.0              h69a702a_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.2.0              h337968e_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.74.1               h606061b_1    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.46.0               hce63b2e_0  
libopenblas               0.3.21          pthreads_h78a6416_3    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libsanitizer              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               haa6b8db_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  12.2.0              h3b97bd3_19    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                h82bc61c_5    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.0                h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.10.3               hca2bb57_4    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
openssl                   1.1.1t               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
pango                     1.50.14              hd33c08f_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.40                hc3806b6_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
python                    3.9.16               h7a1cb2a_0    anaconda
r-base                    4.0.5                hb87df5d_8    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
setuptools                67.6.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.41.1               h5eee18b_0  
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_15    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.40.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.8.4                h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h0b41bf4_2    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.2.1                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h0b41bf4_1003    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.10               h5eee18b_1  
zlib                      1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.4                hc292b87_0
```

Comment: Linux and macOS should work just fine launching RStudio from an active environment. Though there is [a known bug in recent RStudio builds](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12508) for Linux. Maybe you can share more information about the Conda R environment from which you are trying to launch.

Comment: Yes, and it did work exactly once.  Subsequent attempts have all failed, even on bare-bones r-base installations in fresh conda environments.  I edited the question to include package details for the conda environment of interest (because it contains all the libraries I need)

Comment: Please ensure all packages are from Conda Forge - some are coming from `defaults` and `anaconda`, and should be reinstalled with `-c conda-forge`. Especially when it comes to dynamic libraries Conda Forge must has Conda Forge dependencies.

Comment: before I go down that road uninstalling and reinstalling all non-conda-forge packages, would this only pertain to those imported packages (all are already conda-forge)?  Would this also apply to python itself (currently anaconda)?  Or just do everything?

Comment: I’m mainly concerned with the packages of dynamic libraries: e.g., `lib*`, `krb5`, `sqlite`, `xz`, `zstd`, etc. And you don’t have to uninstall - `conda update -c conda-forge` on them should do the trick.